# Custom Font in PySide2 not loading

Tags: pyqt, pyside2

so I am trying to load a custom font in PySide 2.

```
id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(
            f"{path}/design/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        )
families = QFontDatabase.applicationFontFamilies(id)
print(families[0])
QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(
            f"{path}/design/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        )
```

The `print(families[0])` will actually return `Roboto`. So I figure it can be loaded. But when I want to use it in my style sheet.

```py
stylesheet = open('design/style.css').read()
myApp.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

where in the `style.css` this is included:

```
QLabel {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

It will just always throws this error. I also tried all kinds of different spelling like, Roboto-Regular, or Roboto Regular. And nothing seems to work.

```
Populating font family aliases took 55 ms. Replace uses of missing font family "Roboto" with one that exists to avoid this cost
```

Does some see the issue.

Comment: Did you make sure the font is added ***before*** setting the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes the shown code snippets are in order of how are they placed in my script

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on Linux using Qt-5.15.8 with either PySide-5.15.8 or PyQt-5.15.9 (and with the Roboto fonts [downloaded from here](https://github.com/openmaptiles/fonts)).

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but we cannot be sure until we are. Can you provide a complete and self-contained [mre]? Also, as far as I remember, there was a change in the Roboto font related to family names some time ago. Are you completely sure that you're **only** using the latest versions of that font and you don't have *older* versions still installed in your system? What OS and version are you using?

Comment: I used the Google Fonts Version. But using font form the GitHub Repository did not change anything.

@musicamante I will get to an working example later today. But I am own Mac OS Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: @Janosch Note that this could be related to [QTBUG-87267](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-87267) which seems to still exist on macOS even in Qt 15.5.8, meaning that, even if it gets fixed, we'll probably never see it solved for the standard release of Qt 5: the latest available open source version is 5.15.4, there will never be a 5.16 version and all later "patch versions" for 5.15 are only available to subscribers. Also, consider that that should be just a warning, it shouldn't affect the functionality, and since the delay is quite small (55ms), you could even ignore it.

Comment: yes I thought that it might be a OS related issue I will try to see whether it will work on a different OS. But yes you are right this is simply an aestetic c issue.